# What is it about human skin that spiders don't like to walk on?

Tags: animal-behaviour, spider

I'm about to move a spider and I usually use the cup/glass way, but that would seem pretty horrifying if I were the spider.  I'd prefer to use my hands, but they don't seem to like the texture of human skin.  Why?  I've googled and not found anything beyond "they don't like people", which I get.

Comment: I often remove spiders with a plastic cup and a piece of cardboard.   They scurry away quickly when released, so whatever horror they feel seems to be transient.   I don't have the answer to your question, but I imagine I would hate being scooped up by a living creature more than being momentarily confined in a medium-sized room, which is what  a plastic cup might seem like to a spider.   I hope someone can answer, because this is a fascinating question.

Comment: Just moved it - then it waved to me with one leg.  Which just reminded me - why do they sometimes wave their leg at you? (forwards/backwards while being slightly off angle) [I think it's an American grass spider soon to give birth]

Comment: @ab2 - check this out: https://arachnoboards.com/threads/tarantulas-hating-contact-with-human-skin.291707/!  "I'm guessing that it's that they don't generally prefer mushy surfaces that are soft and pliable, because they are less supportive and more likely to give way, causing a potential fall. Falls are bad news for them."  Didn't like the paper towel, either - which would be same consistency!

Comment: even better!: "including not only tarantulas but also amblypygi, phasmids, beetles, mantises, roaches, millipedes, etc. that they don't seem to like abrupt changes to the surface they are walking on. It's like they're comfortable with what they're on, and don't want to switch to something new - whether that "something" is my hand or arm, or a catch cup, or a piece of paper or egg crate or bark. Once they have been on the new surface (such as my hand) for a few minutes and gotten acclimated, they are equally reluctant to get off it - even when that means returning to their former substrate."

Comment: got right onto glass jar from hardwood floor

Comment: Perhaps they instinctively know they are 'prey' creatures themselves.

Comment: Since they are a lot smaller I guess they see the ridges on your skin and immediately understand that it belongs to an animal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [arachnoboards](https://arachnoboards.com/threads/tarantulas-hating-contact-with-human-skin.291707/):

> I'm guessing that it's that they don't generally prefer mushy surfaces that are soft and pliable, because they are less supportive and more likely to give way, causing a potential fall. Falls are bad news for them.

> ...including not only tarantulas but also amblypygi, phasmids, beetles, mantises, roaches, millipedes, etc. that they don't seem to like abrupt changes to the surface they are walking on. It's like they're comfortable with what they're on, and don't want to switch to something new - whether that "something" is my hand or arm, or a catch cup, or a piece of paper or egg crate or bark. Once they have been on the new surface (such as my hand) for a few minutes and gotten acclimated, they are equally reluctant to get off it - even when that means returning to their former substrate.